# NUnit Assert.Equals vs. Assert.AreEqual

Tags: nunit, assert

What is the difference between:

- `Assert.Equals` and `Assert.AreEqual`
- `Assert.NotNull` and `Assert.IsNotNull`
- ...

?

Comment: late comment - in the meanwhile I got to know the `Assert.That` fluent notation which I personally prefer over either of the two above-mentioned variants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just read the documentation:

[NUnit - ConditionAsserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.5.5)

> Two forms are provided for the True,
>   False, Null and NotNull conditions.
>   The "Is" forms are compatible with
>   earlier versions of the NUnit
>   framework, while those without "Is"
>   are provided for compatibility with
>   NUnitLite.

Comment: If the documentation gave the answer then the question wouldn't be needed. I believe you should improve your answer or, if you believe the question to be too unsubstantial for SO, mark the question for deletion. Answers like "Just read the documentation" are aggressive, scares away new users and doesn't add value to SO.

Answer (score 32):

Assert.Equals is an object comparison

Assert.AreEquals is overloaded to compare (int,double, object) etc

Assert.NotNull and Assert.IsNotNul appear to be identical.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.5.5

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749487/what-is-the-usage-of-assert-equals