# Assert.NotNull(object anObject) vs. Assert.IsNotNull(object anObject)

Tags: c#, nunit, assert

There are these two methods in the `NUnit.Framework.Assert` namespace.

I just cannot find what's the difference between them. I'm also curious when to use which one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NUnit Assert.Equals vs. Assert.AreEqual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583633/nunit-assert-equals-vs-assert-areequal)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Two forms are provided for the True, False, Null and NotNull conditions. The "Is" forms are compatible with earlier versions of the NUnit framework, while those without "Is" are provided for compatibility with NUnitLite.

Got it [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.5).